# Floating DIV's to fill unused space

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

When working with a certain API, I am using a function that basically provides me with dozens of categories of settings. To display these, I opted to have a container DIV and split the settings by group (4x 25% width tables) where each group that is parsed appears next.

This is working fine with the small issue of variable amounts of settings, resulting in a lot of unused space being left over. This is caused by me floating everything left, but the longest table causes the next table to appear much further down.

Does CSS support anything that would permit floating these tables into the unused space? I highlighted the largest table on the screenshot for emphasis.

[image]

Comment: Tables are pretty inflexible in terms of alignment and formatting.  If it's not a responsive design and with fixed rows you can absolute position everything, and set top:100px etc.  But if you want everything to wrap nicely, I would ditch the tables and move to divs.  Divs will open a ton of options for responsive and flexible layouts.

Comment: Your question was asked countless times. You're looking for CSS columns, which is the only CSS only solution for your problem. Here's a [decent read](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) on it. Or you can go the `js` route with best options being: Masonry, Isotope, Bootstrap Waterfall and the Pinterest script.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://masonry.desandro.com/

Im using it for a current project it is good. I am currently finding a few issues with Bootstrap and floating elements within a dropdown. Though nothing that will cause me to drop the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Try this JS method:

```
<script>
function renderGrid() {
    var blocks = document.getElementById("container").children;
    var pad = 10,
        cols = 4, //Change this to as much as you want but in this It's 4
        newleft, newtop;
    for (var i = 1; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        if (i % cols == 0) {
            newtop = (blocks[i - cols].offsetTop + blocks[i - cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
            blocks[i].style.top = newtop + "px";
        } else {
            if (blocks[i - cols]) {
                newtop = (blocks[i - cols].offsetTop + blocks[i - cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
                blocks[i].style.top = newtop + "px";
            }
            newleft = (blocks[i - 1].offsetLeft + blocks[i - 1].offsetWidth) + pad;
            blocks[i].style.left = newleft + "px";
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderGrid, false);
window.addEventListener("resize", renderGrid, false);
</script>
```

And now the HTML part:

```
<div id="container">
   <div><p>Your content here!</p></div>
</div>
```

And that's about It but make sure you have an `id="container"` instead of a `class="container"` also add this CSS style Inside your CSS file:

```
#container > div {
position: absolute;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
```

Result: automatic alignment of you divs with automatic top and left element styles.

Hope this works! *-Arqetech*