# Stick all children div close to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap . Loading div(s) inside loop with some data that can be short or long .

I have observed following issue :
[Unwanted space here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dTYc.jpg)

The images shows some unused / unwanted space between the div(s) .

As there are div(s) with different height , how can it possible to overcome this issue and stick each children div to closet of other ?

The following code is running in loop ,

HTML structure :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="row">
    //loop begins
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
           //Some short or very long content here .
        </div>
      </div>
    <div>
    //loop ends
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My study :

[Floating DIV's to fill unused space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336769/floating-divs-to-fill-unused-space)

Tried but not working for me.

Some Hack :

When all children div are of same height such issue doesn't happen.

In my case , setting fixed height to children div(s) is not the solution.

Can any one guide me about this ? May be some article ?

Comment: Check out this CSS only solution: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: or u can use https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Use flexbox, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-7

Comment: @lumio , your solution is working fine on chrome , but not working properly on mozilla . Well my children div(s) got shrinked ? im new to this . Any guidance ?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve this is that you have to add

```
 read more
```

into div if the text content in div is longer than the other div. When user click

```
read more
```

you can pop the div up using bootstrap modal and show all the text ontent in it.

Comment: That is right solution Sorry but my boss wants user to click less buttons !

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the divs doesn't matter much you could use CSS columns:

```css
.row.columns {
  -webkit-columns: 3;
     -moz-columns: 3
          columns: 3
}
.row.columns > .col-md-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .row.columns {
    -webkit-columns: 1;
       -moz-columns: 1;
            columns: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row columns">
  //loop begins
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
         //Some short or very long content here .
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
  //loop ends
</div>
```

The looped items will be set like text in a newspaper, on 3 columns, on devices wider than the `md` breakpoint (which is `992px`, by default, in Bootstrap).

Here's a [more elaborate article](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) on this technique.

---

Another option is to just use [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin. Add an `id` to the parent (the `.row` in your example) and simply use:

```
$('#yourId').masonry();
```

inside the `load` event of your `$(window)`. You can also use a class, but it doesn't make sense to use a `class` if you want to target a single element in the page.

**Note:** I'm not recommending Masonry, but it's popular. Other options are Isotope, Bootstrap-Waterfall and the Pinterest script, which you'll find a few articles about, however, it usually requires a bit of work to apply to a specific layout/case and I don't think anyone wrapped it up as a plugin yet. I might be wrong, though. (Re)search it.

Comment: yes this works , but not 100% . When i apply this "stick to each other" feature on my webpage , the design is messed up a bit . Let me check my internal code , what part is bothering it . I'll reply back once its done good enough .

Comment: @ImDev, I updated my answer with more resources and options. I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#wrapper {
     width: 90%;
     max-width: 1100px;
     min-width: 800px;
     margin: 50px auto;
        }

        #columns {
     -webkit-column-count: 3;
     -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
     -webkit-column-fill: auto;
     -moz-column-count: 3;
     -moz-column-gap: 10px;
     -moz-column-fill: auto;
     column-count: 3;
     column-gap: 15px;
     column-fill: auto;
        }

        .pin {
     display: inline-block;
     background: #FEFEFE;
     border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
     margin: 0 2px 15px;
     -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
     -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
     column-break-inside: avoid;
     padding: 15px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
     opacity: 1;
     
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
     -o-transition: all .2s ease;
     transition: all .2s ease;
        }

        .pin img {
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
     padding-bottom: 15px;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .pin p {
     font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
     color: #333;
     margin: 0;
        }

        @media (min-width: 960px) {
     #columns {
      -webkit-column-count: 4;
      -moz-column-count: 4;
      column-count: 4;
     }
        }

        @media (min-width: 1100px) {
     #columns {
      -webkit-column-count: 5;
      -moz-column-count: 5;
      column-count: 5;
     }
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">        
        </script>
        
        <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="columns">
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNFMT.png" />
       <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
        ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
        ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
        ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI5v7.png" />
       <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. 
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OolSV.png" />
       <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula 
        faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc 
        convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCeyC.png" />
       <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula 
        faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc 
        convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4Yu.png" />
       <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
        sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. 
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2inO.png" />
       <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
        ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
       </p>
      </div> 
      
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CngES.png" />
       <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula 
        faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc 
        convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
        Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBGuW.png" />
       <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. 
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCW6N.png" />
       <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. 
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvc9X.png" />
       <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
        sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla 
        ac urna vestibulum mattis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ADAv.png" />
       <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
        sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla 
        ac urna vestibulum mattis. 
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3SWx.png" />
       <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
        ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
       </p>
      </div> 
      
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hbcm.png" />
       <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
        sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla 
        ac urna vestibulum mattis. 
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILtM0.png" />
       <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
        sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla 
        ac urna vestibulum mattis. 
       </p>
      </div>
     
      <div class="pin">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjihF.png" />
       <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
        ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
        </div>
            
      <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: my children div(s) are getting shrinked up ? Any guidance on that ?

Comment: You wrote your CSS twice. Also you could convert your code to a snippet

Comment: @ImDeveloper pin class has a padding: 15px; maybe that's why shrinking.

Comment: @ShafikulIslam the snippet is looking convincing but somehow , im not getting 100% same result in my code . May be some things like css / layout are conflicting  , i need to little bit work on my internal code . I'll inform result once done .

Comment: @ImDeveloper okay.. :)